# is it possible to create a session variable within a thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Problem is i need to get data from sql server using a stored procedure which usually takes more than 10sec to complete. i was trying to assign this task over to a thread.with in the thread when it gets data,the table is stored in a session variable to be used in the further pages.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate () {Session["dashboardPatientrecords"]=df.getPatients(); });
thread.Start();
```

the thread is working alright pulling the data but as go the next page and try to access the session variable like

```
var dt=(DataTable)Session["dashboardPatientrecords"];
```

the "dt" is set null

please help

thank you

Comment: Assign Session["dashboardPatientrecords"] some value on first page load so that you can determine if session variable in not yet updated by the thread you lauchned? Try writing some log after you add result to Session. Beside all this make sure you do not put big data in session to to save the memory.

Comment: You shouldn't, in general, by splitting off tasks into other threads in asp.net. Also, bear in mind, whatever you do behind the scenes, asp.net is still HTTP - one request generates one response - so if something takes ten seconds, you still need to wait for those ten seconds before you can complete your response. Beyond that, I'm not clear on what your actual problem is here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate a session object with a thread result. Not within a thread though.

```
DataTable dt = null;

var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
      dt = df.getPatients();
    });

thread.Start();
thread.Join();

Session["dashboardPatientrecords"] = dt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,the above code block is working fine but it is making me wait for those 10sec with in the page where the thread is declared

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Cache` instead of `Session`. It's not safe to use session in threading environment.

Comment: how do i achieve it using cache??

Comment: Same as Session, but in this case use Cache object. E.g. Cache["dashboardPatientrecords"] = dt; Read about caching here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
DataTable dt=Session["dashboardPatientrecords"] as DataTable;
```

Comment: The problem is not about casting. It's about populating session object. If it was casting problem then OP would have got exception instead of `null` because of `(type)null` syntax.